# Git Stash while keeping ignored files

Tags: git

As a Git beginner, I am using

- TortoiseGit 1.8.3.0
- git version 1.7.11.msysgit.1

I am working on the master branch with many breaking changes that I do not want to commit yet, but need to immediately add features to the last release. I read that Stash Save is the answer.

I have some files that I use in all versions such as a local configuration config.php, some test files etc. that should not be commited to the remote repository, so they are untracked or ignored.

Tortise Git gives the `include untracked` and `--all` options, and both of them remove ignored files from the reverted working directory.

Is it possible using Tortise Git or otherwise to keep ignored files in the reverted workign directory?

Comment: Would creating a local branch and committing your work there be an untenable solution?

Comment: If I understood correctly, the branch will be pushed to the remote repository? Which is not desirable for me.

Comment: No, if you're creating a local branch, until you specifically push that branch, it will stay local.

Comment: I would go for committing on a temporary branch. It gives you fine grained control over what you are trying to do. You can later reset the temp branch, switch to original branch, and force-delete the temp branch.

Comment: I have nothing against branches, but creating a temporary branch is what `git stash` does (two actually, one for the index and one for the working directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal `git stash` without flags keeps the ignored files intact. They are not removed.

In TortoiseGit this means leaving `include untracked` and `--all` unchecked:

[image: stash with no options]

If you wish to stash (and remove) both your modified and untracked files, but not your ignored files, then use the `include untracked` option (`git stash --include-untracked`):
[image]

Comment: But I would like to stash the untracked as well... can I have best of both worlds?

Comment: Yes, that would be the `include untracked` option (without the `--all` option). That way you stash (and remove) your modified and untracked files, but not your ignored files. (I'll add that to my answer)